# Calling a method inside an accessor C#

Tags: c#, oop, methods, accessor

So I have been struggling with this for quite a while. 
I am trying to learn OOP but this is so big that it is hard for me at least to understand all of it.
Let's say I have a method in a class that gets something from a database.
This data will be set to a variable.
What I do now is have a public method, call it, and then call the accessor with the value. For example:

```
        private string _name;

        public string Name { get { return _name; } }

        public void MyMethod()
        {
            using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM Table WHERE ID = 1", connect))
                {
                    connect.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (reader.Read())
                        {
                            _name = Convert.ToString(reader["Name"]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And I would call it like:

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
myclass.MyMethod();
string myname = myclass.Name;
```

Now this seems really weird to me.
So I thought, maybe it would be worth it to call the method inside the accessor.
Like:

```
public string Name { get { MyMethod(); return _name; } }
```

Calling it like:

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
string myname = myclass.Name;
```

This would result in less code and I can make my method private.
Yet, I would have trouble doing this when the method has parameters to it.
So how do I do this? Is this bad practice? If this is not how I should do this, then how do I do it?

I would really love to hear from you guys! Please don't hesitate to ask questions or make changes to my question.
Also, my sincere apologies if this has been asked already.
Any great tutorials are also really welcome!

Comment: As your MyMethod stands it has no parameters, so you could call it from your constructor, it would then set Name, and name is available.. You can also have MyMethod return name, as well as set name in case you need to pick it up later.. MyMethod could of course return the string.. so you could do String myname = myclass.MyMethod(); there are many options, the one to choose depends on what else you need it to do, what else your class is going to do..  You also, can put public string Name { get { myMethod(); }} if it returned a string..

Comment: You are assigning `Name` to `_name` which is a private field, it is not accessible out of the class.

Comment: @abdul you're missing that there is a public accessor.

Comment: It will work, just keep in mind that (at least in this example) the application will be doing a lot of repetitive database access if the property `Name` gets called a lot.

Comment: @PeterB Yeah I have that in mind. That you very much.

Comment: Additionnal question : Is the `Name` in the BDD subject to any change during the object's life ? I may have a way to reduce database access if it is the case

Comment: @BugFinder So you would suggest I should decide how to do it? There is no "rule" for this kind of issue?

Comment: @Sidewinder94 Hmm, in this case you can assume that it won't change. But I get your concern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are implementing is a form of [Lazy Evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation)
 that is sometimes called *cached property*

The general design pattern is:

```
private SomeType _value;
public SomeType CachedProperty {
     get {
          if(_value == null) {
              _value = GetValue(); // slow
          }
          return _value;
     }
}
```

There is a few reasons that discourage the notion of this kind of property:

- GetValue() is typically slow. Thats why we cashe it's value in the first place. So accessing the property is only slow on the first call. **But** we expect a property to be **always** fast.
- The cashed value might be obsolete by the time we need it again. This can be mitigated by a public method like `UpdateValue`. **But** we expect a property to be **always** up to date.
- If you omit the `_value == null` check, then the property becomes a wrapper for a *method*. Why are we using a property then at all?

So essentially this design patter *hides* the fact that the underlying value is volatile in nature and might cost some time to retreive.

Whether you really want to do this, depends on the demands of the code surrounding you.

But in general I would just go with a typical async pattern:

```
public SomeType GetValue() { ... }
public Task<SomeType> GetValueAsync() { ... }
```

and if you really need to work with a cached value on different scopes add a:

```
public SomeType CachedValue { get; }
```

This clarifies that the value that you get the "fast way", might be outdated.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, I will definately take a look at this.

Answer (score 3):

- You could consider running the method in the ctor, once.
- You could have a public `RefreshData` method which will update all you need from the db.
- You could have the property check whether the `_name` is null, and only if it is - it would update it from database and then return it - otherwise it just returns the existing value. You can combine this with a `Invalidate` method, which will set `_name` and any other relevant member to null or some other indication, to cause their properties to indeed re-call the update function when they are next called.

In real life cases, you will usually know what's the better approach - but they are all OOP.

However the solution you suggested is somewhat against the OOP principles, since the `MyMethod` should probably not be exposed, and your class is probably the one that is responsible for it's data.

---

Also as Jamiec's answer suggests, you should implement the DB-related logic elsewhere, in a Repository class or even a whole layer (separate project sometimes) just for that (look for DAL). This is because that even though your class might be responsible for it's own data - it should not "know" anything about databases or query languages. At most - it knows how to ask something independent of it for some data.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much, this will help me alot!

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to note is that these 2 things (A object holding your data and the method of getting that data) are 2 very different concerns. Good practice dictates that your classes have a [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

In your case, you should have a ["repository"](http://blog.gauffin.org/2013/01/repository-pattern-done-right/) class which knows how to get data from a database and a DTO (or, simply, an Object) which has the properties. Your repository will likely load all the data required and return an object with all the data present.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, I will read the linked pages. This will surely get me further!